# SOQL to get top X from each GROUP

Tags: soql

Say we have data like so

```
Id | Account__c | Some_Field__c
-------------------------------
XX1| 001XXXX300 | Whatever
XX2| 001XXXX300 | Whateve2
XX3| 001XXXX300 | Whateve3
XX4| 001XXXX400 | Else
XX5| 001XXXX400 | Else2
XX6| 001XXXX400 | Else3
XX7| 001XXXX400 | Else4
```

Is there any query that will give me top 3 rows by each Account (has to be SOQL only, no Apex)

```
Id | Account__c | Some_Field__c
-------------------------------
XX1| 001XXXX300 | Whatever
XX2| 001XXXX300 | Whateve2
XX3| 001XXXX300 | Whateve3
XX4| 001XXXX400 | Else
XX5| 001XXXX400 | Else2
XX6| 001XXXX400 | Else3
```

Note: second table has no `Else4`

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "top 3" means? First records related to the account? highest numerical value of a given field?

Comment: `top 3 ORDER BY Id DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've got a custom object you're trying to get. You can do this with a sub-query:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Some_Field__c FROM Children__r ORDER BY Some_Field__c DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 3) FROM Account
```

Comment: Amazing, this is perfect, I hadn't realised that the LIMIT will work in a subquery like so. Thanks as always @sfdcfox. 

All I can say is that you're an amazing contributor to the community and your wealth of knowledge is unparalleled. Thanks for helping everyone!!